# C++ linking error when linking postgresql

Tags: c++, postgresql-9.1

When compiling my code I run into an issue as follows:

```
io.cpp:21: undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
```

as well as all other instances of missing postgres function calls occurring in my code.  Obviously this is a linking problem, I'm just not sure what the link issue is.

I'm compiling with the following:

```
mpiCC -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ decisioning_mpi.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ io.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ calculations.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ rules.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ Instrument.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ Backtest_Parameter_CPO.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ Backtest_Trade_CPO.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -I /usr/include/postgresql/ Data_Bar.cpp
mpiCC -o decisioning_mpi -O2 -g -Wall -Werror -L/usr/lib -lm -lpq decisioning_mpi.o 
io.o calculations.o rules.o Instrument.o Backtest_Parameter_CPO.o Backtest_Trade_CPO.o Data_Bar.o
```

It should be noted that this is the correct directory for *libpq-fe.h* and that I'm linking pq, so I'm not exactly sure why the postgres functions aren't linking correctly.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and installed psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.6 from synaptic.  As well I'll short circuit this, I am using #include "libpq-fe.h".

Any ideas on how I can get this linking issue resolved?

Comment: Put your libraries at the end of the final link command line. (Try a google search for "order of libraries link site:stackoverflow.com" to get quite a few related questions and answers)

Answer (score 1):

put `-L/usr/lib/ -lm -lpq` in the end of link command, the linker can then find the symbols

```
mpiCC -o decisioning_mpi -O2 -g -Wall -Werror decisioning_mpi.o io.o \
calculations.o rules.o Instrument.o Backtest_Parameter_CPO.o \
Backtest_Trade_CPO.o Data_Bar.o -L/usr/lib -lm -lpq
```

GCC Link Reference:
http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I feel like I have egg on my face for it being the order of the linking, here I thought that I had setup postgresql incorrectly.